# call array value with next button click php

Tags: php, jquery

```
echo "Associative 2-dimensional array:<br>";

$marks1=array(
    array("Maths"=>80,"Physics"=>89,"Chemistry"=>79),
    array("Maths"=>90,"Physics"=>78,"Chemistry"=>87),
    array("Maths"=>78,"Physics"=>90,"Chemistry"=>79)
);
echo "<ul>";
for($r=0;$r<count($marks1);$r++)
{
    echo "<li>";
    foreach($marks1[$r] as $key=>$value)
    {
        echo $key." = ".$value."  ";
    }
    echo "</li>";
    echo "<br><br>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

How can i get the click via click button means if i click button gets Maths = 80 Physics = 89 Chemistry = 79
then again i click button gets Maths = 90 Physics = 78 Chemistry = 87
and so on pls suggest

Comment: You need JavaScript for that. PHP is just meant to send data to your web browser.

Comment: Click events are carried out on the client side, for which you will need JavaScript. Ask if you have difficulties in binding click events to fetch data from JS objects.

Comment: any example using above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append the content to a div and increment a counter used like `id post_fix` follow this simple exemple i created for you.

```
<?php 
echo "Associative 2-dimensional array:<br>";

$marks1=array(
    array("Maths"=>80,"Physics"=>89,"Chemistry"=>79),
    array("Maths"=>90,"Physics"=>78,"Chemistry"=>87),
    array("Maths"=>78,"Physics"=>90,"Chemistry"=>79)
);
echo "<ul>";
for($r=0;$r<count($marks1);$r++)
{
    echo "<li>";
    foreach($marks1[$r] as $key=>$value)
    {
        echo "<span id='$key$r'>".$key." = ".$value."</span>  ";
    }
    echo "</li>";
    echo "<br><br>";
}
echo "</ul>";

?>
<button onclick="show()">Show</button>
<div id="here"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i=0;
        function show()
        {

            document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Maths"+i).innerHTML;
            i++;
        }
</script>
```

Hope that will help you.

Comment: thats cool but what i want to call Maths, Physics and Chemistry in a row i.e Maths = 80 Physics = 89 Chemistry = 79 on first click and next click Maths = 90 Physics = 78 Chemistry = 87